# Adding forms to Django DetailView ERROR message:Method Not Allowed (POST)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Hi Djangonauts I am trying to Build a Question and Answer type app like "StackOverflow" or "Quora" I am new to Django. so please forgive any silly mistakes in logic or code. Below is my error

**Before:** I made the question and answer app and it worked fine. The Question Detail page had the Question and an answer button to let the user answer the Question. When the user clicks on the button he goes to a new "`answer_form.html`" writes his answer and clicks `Save` His answer then shows in the Question Detail page. Till here everything worked fine

**The Problem:** Now I don't want the user to leave the Question Detail page post his answer, I used JavaScript to make the `answer_form` to appear on the question detail page, However now when the user clicks `Save` I get a error

```
This page isn’t working
If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405
```

How can I fix this error. I am sure a lot of people don't want people to leave the detail page to comment a post or answer a question. Below are my views and template details

**views.py**

```
class AnswerCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Answer
    form_class = AnswerForm

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.author = self.request.user
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        print(slug)
        self.object.question = get_object_or_404(Question, slug=slug)
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Below are my **forms.py**

```
class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ('text', 'answer_image', 'answer_image2')
```

and below is my **question_detail.html template**

```
 <div class="container-fluid" id="answ" style="display:none">
        <div class="form-group row">
             {{field.errors}}
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% bootstrap_form form2 %}
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('answ').style.display='none'"
                        class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button> # To hide the form
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the button in the template that makes the form show

```
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm col-sm-2"
onclick="document.getElementById('answ').style.display='block'">Answer</a>
```

before this button looked like this and everything worked:

```
<a href="{% url 'questions:add_answer' username=question.user.username slug=question.slug %}>Answer</a>
```

Below are my **Urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/add_answer/$', views.AnswerCreate.as_view(), name='add_answer'),
```

Sure below is the **view.py for QuestionDetail**

```
class QuestionDetail(SelectRelatedMixin, DetailView):
    model = Question
    select_related = ('user', 'group')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username'))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(QuestionDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form2'] = AnswerForm
        return context
```

below is the **URL for QuestionDetail**

```
 url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.QuestionDetail.as_view(), name='single'),
```

Comment: It doesn't seem as though your form is submitting to the right view. You mention a DetailView - is that what is rendering the question_detail template? If so you need to post that view and its URL.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am sorry I missed that. I have added the `view` and `url` for `QuestionDetail` above to my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know how to create the URL to get your form to submit to your CreateView, but you're not using it; you have an empty `action` in the HTML form element so it will just submit back to the same DetailView. You need to use that `{% url %}` tag in the `action` attribute so that the form submits to the right place.

You will probably also want to define `get_success_url()` in your CreateView so that it redirects back to the DetailView.

Comment: It worked, Usually we don't add that in the answer_form.html so I forgot about it. Thank you so much